# Meaning of 'sly illusion'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The students, at least, swore by his name, and Fettes believed himself, and was believed by others, to have laid the foundations of success when he had acquired the favour of this meteorically famous man. Mr. K- was a BON VIVANT as well as an accomplished teacher; he liked a **sly illusion** no less than a careful preparation. In both capacities Fettes enjoyed and deserved his notice, and by the second year of his attendance he held the half-regular position of second demonstrator or sub-assistant in his class.

Another cryptic wording, from Robert L. Stevenson's 'The Body-Snatcher'.

What is the real meaning of 'sly illusion' in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Illusion or allusion?***

Your question is interesting in part because the answer depends on how you come out on a mystery surrounding Stevenson's word choice. Stevenson wrote "The Body Snatcher" in 1884, and [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_Snatcher) it first appeared in print in the *Pall Mall Christmas Extra* of December 1884.

Unfortunately, the Google Books database doesn't include a copy of that periodical, although its handling of the phrase wouldn't be dispositive in any case. The earliest version of the story that a Google Books search finds is from Robert Louis Stevenson, [*St. Ives; The Misadventures of John Nicholson; The Story of a Lie; The Body-Snatcher*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-t8NAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA599&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI9LSs0cPVyAIVRSmICh0-jQDw#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false) (1897), which includes this sentence:

> Mr. K----- was a *bon vivant* as well as an accomplished teacher; he liked a sly **illusion** no less than a careful preparation.

Editions with the same wording appear in [1902](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q9JBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA412&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCTgKahUKEwi-4IOlxtXIAhVB2mMKHco1CUo#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false), [1905](https://books.google.com/books?id=GGYoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA376&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBTgKahUKEwiCtbmzxdXIAhUT_mMKHR1tDgI#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false), [1906](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCdDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA301&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgKahUKEwiCtbmzxdXIAhUT_mMKHR1tDgI#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false), [1909](https://books.google.com/books?id=7DpmjqpRHVQC&pg=PA376&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMI9LSs0cPVyAIVRSmICh0-jQDw#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false), and later. These editions, starting with the one in 1897, are copyrighted by Charles Scribner's Sons.

But another version of the sentence appears in the First Collected Edition of [*The Story of a Lie, and Other Tales*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WLPTAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA247&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+allusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMIjNfO8NTVyAIVDfZjCh2bXwGM#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20allusion%22&f=false) (1904), published by Herbert B. Turner & Co.:

> Mr. K----- was a *bon vivant* as well as an accomplished teacher; he liked a sly **allusion** no less than a careful preparation.

Unlike the Scribner's editions, the Turner edition specifies that "The Body-Snatcher" was originally published in "Pall Mall, Christmas Extra, 1884." Other editions that follow Turner's lead appear in [1906](https://books.google.com/books?id=PhwfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA252&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+allusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCWoVChMI_pzR8cnVyAIVCNZjCh129QXY#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20allusion%22&f=false), [1908](https://books.google.com/books?id=GeA8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA252&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+allusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCGoVChMI_pzR8cnVyAIVCNZjCh129QXY#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20allusion%22&f=false), [1922](https://books.google.com/books?id=m8pDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA465&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+allusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwATgKahUKEwixm-X7ytXIAhVCw2MKHYrHB1k#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20allusion%22&f=false), and later.

It is at least possible that Herbert B. Turner & Co. in 1904 went back to the original version of the story for its edition. In any case, Stevenson, who died in 1894, never saw any of the editions that the Google Books database contains. The 1922 edition is unusual in that it is published by Charles Scribner's Sons—the source of the earliest published version that uses *illusion* instead of *allusion*.

[Editions published as recently as 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=y14oCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT3398&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAWoVChMI9LSs0cPVyAIVRSmICh0-jQDw#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20illusion%22&f=false) have used *illusion* in the cited sentence, and [editions published as recently as 2013](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zt0nCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&dq=%22teacher+he+liked+a+sly+allusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI5cCyzMzVyAIVRlyICh1CrgUp#v=onepage&q=%22teacher%20he%20liked%20a%20sly%20allusion%22&f=false) have used *allusion* there.

---

***What might the two sentences mean?***

If *illusion* is the intended word, my best guess as to the meaning of the words "he liked a sly illusion no less than a careful preparation" is that he (Dr. K) enjoyed a good appearance (or bluff) backed by no real preparation as much as he did a thorough presentation supported by a careful preparation. An illusion seems to be in direct opposition to a careful preparation, not merely in contrast to it.

On the other hand, if *allusion* is the intended word, Stevenson seems to be saying that Dr K enjoyed witty remarks as much as he did a studious approach. The wit and the studiousness might come from the same person, but Dr K didn't favor one characteristic over the other.

In the context of the story, I think that *illusion* is probably the word Stevenson intended. Earlier in the same paragraph, he refers to the medical student Fettes as someone who "had a talent of a kind, the talent that picks up swiftly what it hears and readily retails it for its own." This sounds to me like a description of someone who is clever about presenting work or knowledge as his own, but who actually lifted it from someone else. This description of Fettes does not seem particularly relevant to a later description of Dr K as someone who enjoyed witty conversationalists who pepper their remarks with sly references to other persons and things.

But if *allusion* is incorrect, we can still see why it suggested itself to an editor or typesetter: A talent for alluding to recent events would certainly be strengthened by a concomitant ability to swiftly pick up what one hears and to readily retail (or rather retell) it.